# Raster to vector conversion result shows no "No matches at clicked point." in Inspector

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to conduct separability analysis using Mahanolobis distance to select the best index for classification. I have three indices :NDVI, ReNDVI and LSWI. To conduct the analysis, I'm trying to convert these images to vector format. I have used the following code on NDVI and am able to run the code. But when I use Inspector tool to check the result, I'm getting the message: "No matches at clicked point."

```
//clippedimage2 is the input NDVI image, polygon is study area shapefile 

// NDVI image converted to int

var intNDVI = clippedimage2.toInt16()

// Vector conversion

var vectors = intNDVI.reduceToVectors({

  geometry:polygon,

  crs:clippedimage2.projection(),

  scale:50000,

  geometryType: 'polygon',

  eightConnected: false,

});

Map.addLayer(vectors);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough detail in this question, nor a reproducable example, but it looks like your problem is that you're using a scale to 50,000m per pixel.  Likely, when computd at that scale, there's no data in your inputs or your region is smaller than that.

Comment: After reducing the scale, the polygon is visible and the issue is resolved.